# How do I preserve changes to a theme's functions.php across updates?

Tags: functions, themes

I'm using a theme called ["Pinboard"](http://wordpress.org/themes/pinboard), version 1.1.0.

I made some edits to the theme's functions.php in order to display [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons before archive titles. For instance, if you're browsing the "foo" tag, then up in the header, where it reads "Currently browsing tag foo", there's a tag icon to the left of "foo". These are the changes I made; they're in the "Highlight current location in the archive" section of functions.php, around line 1306:

```
elseif( is_author() ) {
                    $author = get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
                    echo '<i class="icon-user"></i> ' . $author->display_name;
                } elseif ( is_year() ) {
                    echo '<i class="icon-calendar"></i> ' . get_query_var( 'year' );
                } elseif ( is_month() ) {
                    echo '<i class="icon-calendar"></i> ' . get_the_time( 'F Y' );
                } elseif ( is_day() ) {
                    echo '<i class="icon-calendar"></i> ' . get_the_time( 'F j, Y' );
                } elseif ( is_category() ) {
                    single_term_title( '<i class="icon-bookmark"></i> ' );
                } else {
                    single_term_title( '<i class="icon-tag"></i> ' );
                }
```

You can see that I'm echoing `<i></i>` elements with certain classes.

I want to preserve these changes between upgrades of Pinboard, but as it stands, updating the theme will obliterate my changes and require me to add them again by hand.

What can I do to preserve these changes across upgrades? Is this a place where child themes would be useful, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Make a child theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Can't say it any clearer. @s_ha_dum already said it in fact. Creating a Child Theme allows for almost any customisation to a theme, customisation that won't be lost when updating a (parent) theme. The Wordpress Codex entry for [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) takes you through the whys and wherefors.
It's extremely simple to create a Child Theme (see link to codex). In fact, you only need a stylesheet that imports the Parent theme stylesheet.

Once you have your Child theme in place, look through your site (and brain) to work out where you placed/made any customisations (you mention functions.php but did you create any custom templates for example? Or perhaps you edited ones in the Parent theme?). You'll need to copy these changes into your child theme folder e.g. a new functions.php, styles.css or template-i-modified.php.